# Robolectric - How to clean up message: "WARNING: unknown service autofill"

Tags: android, robolectric

During my tests with Robolectric, I always get a warning message in console (no LogCat) with says: "WARNING: unknown service autofill".

Does Anyone know what to do to clean it up?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the sdk version to 25. Thereby the tests will run against api level 25. The warnings should be removed/implemented in future robolectric versions.

To set the sdk version see: http://robolectric.org/configuring/

Comment: I have SDK version to 26 and it's the same.

Comment: I put default sdk version to 25 and only for several specific test I set it to 26. So I don't have these warnings and I still can test some new notification API

Comment: @EugenMartynov, could you provide details?

Answer (score 0):

The following configurations worked for me,

```
@Config(sdk = 21)
public class MyClassTests {
/* testCodeHere */
}
```

Other sdk Config that worked fine =

- `@Config(sdk = 22)`
- `@Config(sdk = 23)`
- `@Config(sdk = 24)`
- `@Config(sdk = 25)`

This error happens when running tests against `sdk = 26`.
Therefore, as @Moritz suggested,
change the `sdkVersion` in your tests or create a `robolectric.properties` file, [Configuring Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/configuring/).

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded from SDK 24 to 26 and began seeing this error. Going back to SDK 25 didn't seem like a good solution so I tried upgrading Robolectric to its latest stable version.

At time of writing this is version 3.8.
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.robolectric/robolectric/3.8

This fixed the problem for me.

From the sounds of it, they fixed this in 3.7
https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/releases/